# Graphing the decoherence of qubits being used to perform an algorithm

Tags: programming, qiskit, decoherence, ibm-quantum-devices

How would I be able to graph the decoherence of qubits being used to perform an algorithm? I'm working with the IBMQ Qiskit framework and I'm trying to write a program that allows me to find the decoherence of qubits. But I do not know if IBMQ has a method to do that. Can anyone help me, or point me the right direction to implement such a thing?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/qiskit/ignis/relaxation_and_decoherence.ipynb) Qiskit tutorial might be able to point you in the right direction. It explains how to use the Ignis element of Qiskit to find relaxation ($T_1$) and decoherence ($T_2$) times of qubits.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly, it's a little bit difficult to find related examples except matthew mentioned. The link is out of date and the update one is here:

[2_relaxation_and_decoherence](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/noise/2_relaxation_and_decoherence.html)

[2_relaxation_and_decoherence.ipynb](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/noise/2_relaxation_and_decoherence.ipynb)

It contains lots of figures, perhaps they are what you want.